# Accessing user presence with REST API for Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'd like to query both my own presence and other users' presences in Teams.  Ideally I would like to receive notifications when they change so I can change my internal state.

The graph API doesn't appear to have this functionality today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet available. We do have plans to add this to Microsoft Graph but we do not have an ETA.

Comment: Eagerly waiting for this functionality. Any updates @Bill ?

Comment: The last I've heard, from this Teams/Skype MVP, is that it is slated for availability in the second half of 2019, so hopefully soon... 
https://tomtalks.blog/2019/02/presence-status-api-coming-for-microsoft-teams-targeted-for-h2-cy2019/

Answer (score 5):

The API for the presence is now in beta: [Graph Api beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0)