# How to get the current status of a Microsoft Teams user

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

Is there an API where I can get the current Status of a Team User ? Like "Available", "In Meeting" etc ?
I have used the user's presence on Skype For Business using the 2013 lync SDK. I am not finding anything similar for Teams. Ultimately my goal is to find the current status and display it on an IOT Device.
Any code snippet, links will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Graph API endpoints to get presence information is now available in beta version. Please check [Graph API - Presence resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/presence?view=graph-rest-beta#methods)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is available yet.

Please check the following post:

[[Accessing user presence with REST API for Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448561/accessing-user-presence-with-rest-api-for-microsoft-teams][1])

Comment: Upon further research and based on this link https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-AMA/Presence-API/m-p/339535
It seems like almost a year after the commitment for a "Teams" API, theres no progress.

Comment: Microsoft announced at Ignite 2019 that there is a presence API (beta) being released within the next 2 weeks (so sometime now).  So there is *something* coming soon that people can play with.